# Docker - No rule to make target `hiredis'

Tags: linux, docker, redis, dockerfile, centos

I have been scratching my head since past 2 days for this issue. I am using amazon linux image and trying to install redis through a Dockerfile, but this doesn't work.

```bash
RUN yum install -y java-17-amazon-corretto.x86_64
RUN yum install -y tar
RUN yum install -y wget
RUN yum -y update
RUN yum -y install gcc make

RUN wget http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz
RUN tar xvzf redis-stable.tar.gz
RUN cd redis-stable/deps
make hiredis jemalloc linenoise lua geohash-int
cd ..
make install
```

Comment: why don't you use the official redis image? instead of building it yourself? `docker pull redis`

Comment: Is there any punctuation in the last four lines; are they one `RUN` command, or four?  (Mostly relevant because `RUN cd` in its own command doesn't actually do anything.)

Comment: I think sir David Maze is right, ```RUN cd``` did nothing so you should try ```WORKDIR``` and ```make -C ``` instead.

Answer (score 0):

When I [follow the docs](https://redis.io/docs/getting-started/installation/install-redis-from-source/), it says run `make` and `make install` from the root of the install directory.

```bash
RUN cd redis-stable
RUN make
RUN make install
```